# Downside to using *.herokuapp.com domain?

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, cloudflare

I need to point thousands of TLDs to the same Rails app hosted in Heroku.

So far I have automated the process of adding domains to CloudFlare and Heroku, but SSL has proven to be a challenge.

- Heroku has ACM **on** by default, which will fail when the CF orange cloud is on (which I need on).
- I can't turn ACM **off** with `Flexible SSL` in CloudFlare because I need SSL from edge to origin.
- I can't use an Origin CA because Heroku only supports 1 certificate per app (not per domain) and I'm going to be well over 100 domains. I also don't want to have to manage multiple certificates which contain multiple TLDs and re-generate the certificate with every single domain in it every time I add a new domain.

**Question:** Is there a downside to just pointing `www` and `@` to `my-app.herokuapps.com`?

So far it works perfectly from a DNS perspective with `Full SSL` in CloudFlare, even though it says in Heroku docs that the `herokudns.com` strategy is encouraged. I just wanted to ensure there aren't any deprecations or hidden limits that will suddenly make this stop working after I've committed to it.

I'm also open to any other solutions.

Comment: have you learned anything new here?  Thanks!

Comment: Heroku support said it was totally fine... although without a lot of details :;/